# Increment a number and append a fixed set of characters - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to increment a number and append AA as prefix. Below is the example:

I have a constant number stored in a table T1.
I have to increment that number by 1 with each record from another table. Also, the number should have 'AA' as prefix.

The records should look like below:

```
AA1010
AA1011
AA1012...so on
```

Edit: My query should start with Select and nothing else. As the system does not accept a query starting other than 'Select'. Many thanks to those who answered my question. Waiting for the reply based on my edit. Thanks guys.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In standard SQL, you would write a `select` query as:

```
select t.*,
       concat('AA', t1.val + row_number() over (order by ?))
from t1 cross join
     othertable t;
```

You can also use `||` as an operator for string concatenation.

The `?` is a placeholder for the column name that you want to order by.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, use `+` for string concatenation and convert the types to strings:

```
select t.*,
       ('AA' + convert(varchar(255), t1.val + row_number() over (order by ?)))
from t1 cross join
     othertable t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a beginner and had to work a lot on the query to get it right. You response was really helpful. Although I got the value to increment, but I am unable to append 'AA'. I used +, but it is giving me an error that cannot convert varchar to numeric. I cannot use concat as system does not accept it. I also tried to put this whole query into a inner query and append AA to the inner query result. But it is still giving me error that it expects a condition. Any further suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: @Sara . . . What database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you:-

```
DECLARE @constnumber INT =0 

SELECT @constnumber = [constant number] 
FROM   t1 

UPDATE t1 
SET    [constant number] = @constnumber + 1 

SELECT 'AA' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, @constnumber + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cid int = 0;

SELECT @cid = [const_column] FROM t1;

UPDATE T2
SET [const_column] = CONCAT('AA', @cid = @cid +1),
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012+

```
DECLARE @cid int = 0;
SELECT @cid = [const_column] FROM t1;

create Sequence Sq as int
minvalue @cid
cycle;

update t2 set [const_column]=(concat('AA', NEXT VALUE FOR Sq ))
```